# Add base64 image to another image in PHP

Tags: php, image

I'm creating dynamic image in PHP with this:

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(708, 500);
```

Then I add some customization, background color, watermark text...

```
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, 708, 500, $whiteColor);
imagettftext($image, $fontsize - 3, 0, 400, 500 - $fontsize + 3, $infoColor, $fontfile, $info);
```

And finaly save the file:

```
imagepng($image, "test.png");
```

Everything works well, I get that `test.png` with white background, watermark, everything.

But this PHP file also receive `POST` values from JSON, one of them is base64 image. I know I can use something like that:

```
$stringImage = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($data->image));
```

But I don't know how to embed that posted image to my dynamicaly created image. Is that even possible?

**Note:** yes, base64 image is valid image

Comment: I mean you want to combine the two images as two layers one picture over a the other to print your watermark on it? Yes it is possible ;) I know typo3 is doing it on serverside by imagemagic but it should also be possible with pure php. My first hit for doing this is: http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecopymerge.php

Comment: Thanks for reply, but Mateusz already post answer and `imagecopy` was good enought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using imagecopy() ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

Comment: Thanks, that's it! Now I have to found nice cords.